# Java Class обращение к полям классов

Tags: java

Существует класс `A`, в котором есть определенное поле:

```
public class A {

private int a;  

public int getA() 
       { return a;}

  public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Так же есть класс `B`, в котором, с помощью кнопки я реализую данное поле

```
public class B extends JFrame{

  private JLabel label;
  private JButton button;
  private JButton button2;

  A gg = new A();
  C pp = new C();


public b() {

label = new JLabel(gg.getA());
button = new JButton("Narashivanie");
button2 = new JButton("Change");

JToolBar tq = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

tq.add(label);
tq.add(button);
tq.add(button2);

tq.setFloatable(false);

add(tq, BorderLayout.CENTER);


button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                a.setA(a.getA() + 1);
                updateCountA();
            }
        });

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pp.Change();
                updateCountA();
            }
        });
}

private void updateCountA(){
   label.setText(a.getA());
}
```

И есть класс `C`, в котором имеется метод:

```
public class C {

  A gk = new A();

  public void Change(){    
     gk.setA(0); 
  }
}
```

---

Вопрос вот в чем: почему метод `Change` у меня не работает?

И дайте совет, чем лучше пользоваться во фрейме, чтобы упорядочить элементы?
Признаюсь, сам не разбирался, нашел только удобный `ToolBar` и всё..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас два отдельных независимых объекта класса `A`. Один в поле класса `B`:

```
A gg = new A();
```

А другой — в поле класса `C`:

```
A gk = new A();
```

Когда вы пишете `new`, вы получаете новый объект. Судя по коду, вам хочется, чтобы это был один и тот же объект. Этого можно добиться, например, добавив в класс `C` конструктор:

```
public class C {
  final A gk;

  public C(A a) {
      gk = a;
  }

  public void Change(){    
      gk.setA(0); 
  }
}
```

И вызвав его с существующим объектом `A` в классе `B`:

```
A gg = new A();
C pp = new C(gg);
```

Теперь и `B.gg`, и `C.gk` указывают на один и тот же объект.

Comment: Именно такого ответа я и ожидал, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

потому что это не статическая функция

вместо

```
C.Change();
```

попробуйте

```
pp.Change();
```

Comment: Исправил, все равно не работает :)

Comment: до `actionPerformed` доходит?

Comment: Я не знаю. И не знаю как это проверить. Я только начал программировать: создание классов, обращение к полям, основы ООП, всё это легко и понятно. Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой :) 
Все предыдущие кнопки, которые я программировал, работают отлично. А тут вообще беда..

Comment: @OgneFF: А вы книжку по Java прочитали какую-нибудь?

Comment: @VladD да, Thinking in Java 4th edition  прочел)

Comment: @OgneFF: Окей, тогда я спокоен.

Answer (score 0):

меня смущает конструкция вида

```
a.setA(a.getA() + 1);
```

может всё таки

```
gg.setA(gg.getA() + 1);
```

Comment: Да, все правильно, извиняюсь за неточности в коде, надеюсь смысл моей вопроса я правильно донес